# How can I have multiple collections in Solr

Tags: database, solr, lucene

Hi I am new to Solr and I'm trying to get my bearings.
Using Solr in my case might not be the best idea or might be a bit overkill but this is just for testing to see how to use it.

I would like to create a database which handles users posts and pages, in mongodb I would have created  a collection for users, a collection for post and a collection for pages which would obviously contain the individual documents.

I don't know how would I be able to replicate that in Solr . I have created a core for users which I thought is like a collection in mongodb. To add a post on Pages, do I then create a new core for each or is there another way to separate the data?

Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have separate collection in solr as well.
With the latest version of solr where you can use solr cloud and create multiple collections.

Each collection can handle a separate entity.

Please refer the below links for more details

[Solr Collection API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/collections-api.html)

[Solr Collection Management](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/collection-management.html)